# How to display items of array from last to first item?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have an array with items. I want to render all items in reverse, without changing the order of the array.

```
var array = [2,5,3,5,8,4,1];
array.map(item => {
return(<div>{item}</div>)    
})

//this will display: 2 5 3 5 8 4 1  
//but i want to display: 1 4 8 5 3 5 2
```

To be clear, I dont want to reverse the actual array because I need to be able to add new values into the array. All I want is to map the array in reverse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this method before you map...

```
let reverse = [...arr].reverse()
```

or even better...

```
[...array].reverse().map(item => {
    return(<div>{item}</div>)    
})
```

Comment: hi, i dont want to reverse array i want to be like original array because i want to add new ellements in array and to display not reversed array  on another place

Comment: var reversed = array.reverse();                                                                                                          will this change original array?? or array will be the same?

Comment: Then use "array.reverse().map...". This does save the original array in reverse, it just reverses the mapping order.

Comment: var reversed = array.reverse() creates a new array in reverse. You can then use it like this: "reversed().map...".

Comment: @NoahGwynn According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse reverse is an in place operation, meaning that `array` will be reversed, not just the map.

Comment: You can clone the array before the reverse (with, in the following example, spread syntax) so you have some thing like: `[...array].reverse().map(item => { return(<div>{item}</div>) })`

Comment: sry my english is bad,  on youre first comments y said       "Then use "array.reverse().map...". This does save the original array in reverse, it just reverses the mapping order. "            do you want to say  "Then use "array.reverse().map...". This does not save the original array in reverse, it just reverses the mapping order. " ??

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Thanks Ben!

Comment: I made a mistake here. Do what Ben is suggesting: [...array].reverse().map(item => { return(<div>{item}</div>) })

Comment: I think you might have one `.map` too many in this answer. :)

Comment: Thanks for spotting that Ben

Answer (score 0):

You can try a solution without explicitly using `reverse`:

```js
var array = [2,5,3,5,8,4,1];

var arrayOutput = array.map((valye, index, inputArray) => inputArray[(inputArray.length - 1) - index]);

console.log(arrayOutput);
```

But, for a better understanding of basic loop mechanics, you can try the following constructions:

```js
/* your array */
var array = [2, 5, 3, 5, 8, 4, 1];

/* loop forward from 2 to 1, 
 * when 'l = array.length' is number of array elements */
for (let i = 0, l = array.length; i < l; i++)
{
  console.log(array[i]);
}
```

```js
/* your array */
var array = [2, 5, 3, 5, 8, 4, 1];

/* loop backward from 1 to 2, 
 * when 'array.length-1' is last element of array */
for (let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
{
  console.log(array[i]);
}
```